# Clipped Button in css not as Expected

Tags: html, css, clip-path

[image]

Expected
[image]

```css
.clipped-button {
 height: 42px;
   min-width:120px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
border:none;
  border-radius:2px;
  align-items:center;
clip-path: polygon(0px 0%, 0px 60%, 18px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 40%, calc(100% - 18px) 0px);
  padding: 2.625px;
background-color: #993029;
}
.btn {
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  

    background-color: rgb(205, 65, 58);
  display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
  align-items:center; 
    clip-path: polygon(0px 0%, 0px 60%, 16px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 40%, calc(100% - 16px) 0px);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<button class="clipped-button"><div class="btn">Click Me</div>
</button>
```

Not getting the clipped corners rounded
Please help to round the clipped corners at top right and bottom left if possible

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a clip-path perhaps something similar to the following is an option.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(190, 40, 40);
  background-color: rgba(200, 60, 60, 0.6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(200, 60, 60, 0.8));
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  /*--background-color: rgba(200, 60, 60, 1.0); --alt color--*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(250, 100, 100, 1.0));
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\1F846 \1F846';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -2px;
  right: -40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"><span> Click Me </span></button>
```